# R Shiny, monitoring a variable and updating ui

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create a message system in a shiny app, that gets notifications when certain tasks are done, but presently it does not work:

UI:

```
library(shinydashboard)
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard",
                  dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu")
),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody("Hi", actionButton("go", label="DO STUFF!"), actionButton("go2", label="DO MORE STUFF!"))
)
```

Server:

```
library(shinydashboard)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  M_Store <- reactiveValues(DF = data.frame(
    from = c("Admininstrator", "New User", "Support"),
    message = c(
      "Sales are steady this month.",
      "How do I register?",
      "The new server is ready."
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ))

  output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
    msgs <- apply(M_Store$DF, 1, function(row) {
      messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])
    })
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
  })

  reactive({
    input$go
    message("Button pressed. Execute analysis!")
    message("Pretend analysis got done!")
    message("Now want to send a message that the analysis is done!")
    M_Store$DF <- rbind(isolate(M_Store$DF), data.frame(from="Meee", message="Done message!"))
    })

  reactive({
    input$go2
    message("Second button pressed. Execute second analysis!")
    message("Some computation!")
    message("Want to update the user on progress with a message!")
    M_Store$DF <- rbind(isolate(M_Store$DF), data.frame(from="Someone else!", message="Progress message2!"))
    message("More computations....")
    message("Done, want to tell user I'm done!")
    M_Store$DF <- rbind(isolate(M_Store$DF), data.frame(from="Someone else!", message="Done message2!"))
  })
})
```

You see my intention? I'd like to be able to push messages of analysis or action progress. I thought having a reactive DF in M_Store would mean whenever it is manipulated, then so is anything depending on it i.e. output$messageMenu.

What I'd like to do is analogous to shiny's progress bars: as your doing your computation you just update their variable, and they change on the screen.

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reactiveValues` function in combination with `isolate`. Your case would look something like:

```
messageData <- data.frame(from = character(0),  message = character(0), stringsAsFactors = F) #simplified this a bit

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  M_Store <- reactiveValues(DF = messageData)

  newMessage <- reactive(data.frame(from = as.character(input$from),message = as.character(input$message)))
  observe({
    M_Store$DF <- rbind(isolate(M_Store$DF), newMessage())
  })

  output$myUI <- renderUI({

   #some code
   ... M_Store$DF ...
   #some code

  })
})
```

`M_Store$DF` is now a reactive value. When *either* of `input$from` or `input$message` change
, `newMessage` will change, which will in turn `rbind` a new row. If `M_Store` is within any `renderUI` function, it will update that value as wll.

If I get what you are trying to do, you might want to change newMessage to an `eventReactive`, so that a user needs to push a button to commit any changes (vs. it firing every time either input changes).

**EDIT:**

Based on your edit above, you want the following instead of your reactive functions:

```
observeEvent(input$go,{
    message("Button pressed. Execute analysis!")
    message("Pretend analysis got done!")
    message("Now want to send a message that the analysis is done!")
    M_Store$DF <- rbind(isolate(M_Store$DF), data.frame(from="Meee", message="Done message!"))
  })
```

This fires everytime the value of `input$go` changes (every time the button is pressed). If you put other input or reactive values here, you can tie it to other processes or ui elements

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have it so as when someone does some action, say load in data, or do some analysis, after the action is completed, a message will be pushed to the messageData, and displayed in the UI. The specific message will be generated when certain reactive expression e.g. a t-test, which relies on inputs, finishes.

Comment: I've just edited the question to show with a toy example exactly what I want to do. (Doesn’t work though)